# Load entire dict into a particular dataframe cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
df =  
columnA   columnAB
row1       xxx  
row2       yyy
row3       zzz
row4       xyx

expected df =  
columnA   columnAB  columnB
row1       xxx      [('A1(80)', ['BB11', 'A11', 'A21']), ('B1(70)', ['CC55', 'HH21']), ('C1(60)', ['KK88'])]
row2       yyy
row3       zzz
row4       xyx

from collections import defaultdict

d1, d2 = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(list)

d = {'A1BB11': 10,  
     'B1CC55': 20,  
     'A1A11':  30,  
     'A1A21':  40,  
     'B1HH21': 50,  
     'C1KK88': 60
    }

for k, v in d.items():
    prefix = k[:2]
    d1[prefix] += v
    d2[prefix].append(k[2:])

final = {'{}({})'.format(k, d1[k]): v for k, v in d2.items()}

print(final)
# {'A1(80)': ['BB11', 'A11', 'A21'],
#  'B1(70)': ['CC55', 'HH21'],
#  'C1(60)': ['KK88']}
```

Now I need to load this data in a dataframe cell, I tried converting this into list and load

```
final = sorted(final.items())  
# type(final) = <class 'list'>  

df.loc[df['columnA'].str.contains('row1', na=False), 'columnB'] = final
```

But I run into error
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

could you suggest a way to handle this

Comment: what's your `df` structure? Also, post the final expected result

Comment: updated the problem statement with df and expected df